# Calls go through even when notifications disabled

Tags: notifications, calls, silent-mode

I disable all notifications in app notifications menu and text notifications do not show, as intended, but calls go through... no notification is shown when someone calls, but the call sound rings. So it is impossible to fully silence specific apps.

System details are:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deny/Remove the phone, messaging, etc permissions of that app